# Handling external links in Triage questions

Tags: discussion, triage, external-links

While reviewing some Triage questions I came across this question:

[Ionic/AngularJs Controller Initialization ng-init doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980060/ionic-angularjs-controller-intialization-ng-init-doesnt-work)

My immediate thought was that it contained a link that I wouldn't really feel safe clicking so I was that I should flag it.  The issue is that I don't know if there is any rules regarding posting external links such as the one in that post that I could use to justify flagging it.

I have looked everywhere that I can think of to see if there is any rules that could give me a black and white answer to this question.

For future reference in case the post is edited or removed the link in the question was:

```
https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/accountant
```

Is there somewhere on `SO` rules or in an `SO Meta` question that provides guidelines for handling external links in questions?

**Update**
I just came across this question as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8533718

It also contains a link that I wouldn't feel safe clicking on either and I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: The problem with external links (assuming they are not spam) is that if they go 404 the question might become useless. As a general rule I use, the question should be answerable without visiting that link.

Comment: In your first linked question, it looks to me like the link added to the question is meant to give a live demo of the issue the OP is seeing. They _also_ included the relevant code, so really, the link is just there for support. In that case, the first question is actually fine with the link in it. (Though it could use a bit better of a problem description in case the link _does_ ever go down.)